# Primary display won't turn on if second display unplugged

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

- Kubuntu 16.04
- GeForce GTX 460
- 390.25 drivers
- HP ZR24i display, plugged in through DVI
- SONY KDL40W600B 40" TV, plugged in through HDMI

I have the monitor set to primary in the display settings. This wasn't happening last year, and it suddenly is now. I haven't installed or changed anything that I am aware of that is relevant. I just updated the driver yesterday to see if it would fix it, but it doesn't.

What happens is that when I unplug the HDMI cable from the TV so that I can plug something else into it, the primary display (the monitor) goes black. I can ctrl-alt-F1 into a terminal, but when I do ctrl-alt-F7 to go back to the desktop, the screen is just black again.

It was not doing this last year. Yesterday is the first time I tried unplugging it again (irrelevantly, to plug in a console), and this happened. when I tried to do startx from the terminal, I saw a line that said something along the lines of "NVIDIA: wrong # of displays in RAID". The thing is, I don't remember setting any such thing up or agreeing to do it automatically.

I don't see anything relevant in nvidia-settings for this. I need to be able to unplug the TV without losing the primary display. This used to work perfectly fine and I don't know what happened.

(The TV does have multiple HDMI ports, but only one fits the graphics card and console both, the others are a different, more square-ish shape).

Comment: The one with the more squarish shape you have described I am pretty sure is actually display port so it is not an HDMI cable.  I personally don't know enough about kde right now and multiple moniotrs but no nvidia settings is not what you want. what you want with proprietary nvidia drivers is something that manages the xrandr.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my GTX 1080. Unplug all displays from the computer and boot it. Then plug in your monitor and adjust settings if needed and then you can plug in whatever else. Hopefully this helps..